# Thumbnail Image from Firebase refusing to load

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a video from firebase that I am trying to grab the first frame from so I can get a thumbnail image for UIPurposes. I am using this function to grab the image. However it keeps giving me an error stating that

> *** Error generating thumbnail: The operation could not be completed
>   nil

```
func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {

    do {

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path , options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return thumbnail

    } catch let error {

        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil

    }

}
```

I checked the url and the video is there so im not sure where the error is coming from.

> "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FME%2FMVLATjHBMmSYGBAOH8s8aCROmXg2%2F2018-11-16T06:38:26Z.mp4?alt=media&token=e005d87a-1c1d-4edd-a550-b6a8f4554197"

This function also locks up the UI

Comment: Can you print the error rather than error. localizedDescription you might be missing additional data.

Comment: what do you mean @SachinVas

Comment: print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")

Comment: umm it might be working now...I think I fixed it the only thing I don't like now is that it is locking up the UI @SachinVas

Comment: It looks like the main thread is occupied with some task. Instead of returning a UIImage, return the cgImage object from function and call the function on a background thread.

Comment: @SachinVas want to show an example I could give you credit

Comment: Hey @BoJackson what exactly did you do to get it fixed? Thanks im facing the same problem currently